# Android socket streaming

Tags: android, websocket, httpurlconnection, ksoap2

**SOLVED** 
I am connecting to a soap service that will post events to my application.  I am having difficulty figuring out how to listen to the connection for the updates.  Here are my 2 possible connection functions that I have put together to connect to the service.  I am just not sure where to go from here.

```
public HttpURLConnection Subscribe2() throws IOException {
            reset();
            URL url = new URL("http://" + msHostAddx + "/services");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +
                Base64.encodeToString((msUser + ":" + msPassword).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",
                SOAP_ACTION);
            OutputStream reqStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            String xmlRequest = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ns=\"http://www.universal-devices.com/wsdk/isy/3.0\">\n" +
                "<soap:Header/>\n" +
                "<soap:Body>\n" +
                "<ns:Subscribe>\n" +
                "<reportURL>REUSE_SOCKET</reportURL>\n" +
                "<duration>infinite</duration>\n" +
                "</ns:Subscribe>\n" +
                "</soap:Body>\n" +
                "</soap:Envelope>";
            reqStream.write(xmlRequest.getBytes());
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            return conn;
    }

public InputStream Subscribe() throws IOException {
    reset();
    try {

      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
      request.addProperty("reportURL","REUSE_SOCKET");
      request.addProperty("duration","infinite");

      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
      envelope.dotNet = true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
      envelope.env = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";

      HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
      List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<>();

      headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode((msUser+":"+msPassword).getBytes())));
      androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

      androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);


      SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
      //Do something with response

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the below.

```
    int content_length = 0;
    StringBuffer headerBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    int charValue;
    do {
      try {
        while ((charValue = reader.read()) != -1) { //CONTINUE READING TILL END OF INPUT
          headerBuffer.append((char) charValue);
          if (charValue == '\n') {
            int index = headerBuffer.length();
            if (index >= 4) { //Check for end of header data
              if (headerBuffer.charAt(index - 2) == '\r' &&
                  headerBuffer.charAt(index - 3) == '\n' && headerBuffer.charAt(index - 4) == '\r') {
                content_length = getContentLength(headerBuffer.toString());

                if (content_length < 0)
                  break;
                byte messageBuffer[] = new byte[content_length];
                int num_read = 0;
                do {
                  int r = reader.read(messageBuffer, num_read, content_length - num_read);
                  if (r == -1)
                    break;
                  num_read += r;
                } while (num_read < content_length);
                //DO STUFF with messageBuffer
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printstacktrace();
      }
      headerBuffer.setLength(0);
    } while (true);
```